# How to deserialize JSON string using standard setters

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I am using jackson-core, databind, annotations 2.3.3 jars.  I have the following simple class

```
public class ClassA {
    private int value;

    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

And here is the code to try to deserialize a JSON string to the object:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

...

final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
ClassA request = objectMapper.readValue("{\"Value\": 1}", ClassA.class);
```

But I am getting the following error:
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "Value" (class ClassA), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "value"])
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@3bff5976; line: 1, column: 12] (through reference chain: ClassA["Value"])

If I changed the JSON string to lower case then it worked.  I thought Jackson would be able to map the value to the setter by following the setter convention.  I understand i could add JsonProperty annotation to ClassA to make it work but I cannot modify ClassA in my situation.

I also tried explicitly enabling the following mapping features before calling readValue, but it still got the same error:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MapperFeature;

...

objectMapper.enable(MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_GETTERS);
objectMapper.enable(MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_SETTERS);
```

How can I have Jackson bind to standard getters/setters (getXxx and setXxx) without specify annotation to the class being bound?

Thanks!

Comment: I think it is because your JSON string is `Value` instead of `value`. Are your JSON properties going to be capitalized like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is happening because of the default `PropertyNamingStrategy` provided by Jackson. From the [documentation](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategy.html):

> In absence of a registered custom strategy, default Java property
>   naming strategy is used, which leaves field names as is, and removes
>   set/get/is prefix from methods (as well as lower-cases initial
>   sequence of capitalized characters).

The mapper default uses the Java default property naming strategy. If your JSON properties are Pascal Case (not sure because you only provided 1 property) then you can give the mapper the [`PascalCaseStrategy`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategy.PascalCaseStrategy.html).

```
final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(new PropertyNamingStrategy.PascalCaseStrategy());
ClassA request = objectMapper.readValue("{\"Value\": 1}", ClassA.class);
```

Comment: Using the PropertyNamingStrategy works for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Jackson follows bean naming conventions.

> I understand i could add `JsonProperty` annotation to `ClassA` to make it work but I cannot modify `ClassA` in my situation.

That's where mixins come in handy. Create an `abstract` class that has the same method declarations (same getters for example) as `ClassA` and annotate them with the appropriate `@JsonProperty` annotation. You then register the mixin with the `ObjectMapper` and voila! The `ObjectMapper` will now use the mixin class as a template for serializing and deserializing `ClassA`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Sotirios.  In my case I have many classes involved in the deserialization and it is quite a bit of work to manually create an abstract class for each one of them.